# Removing a fragment and give its space to another

Tags: android, fragment, hide, show-hide

I have 3 fragments on my activity and i want to hide one of them on the click of a button....
now that's easy using the **FrameTransaction** to hide it following this answer in
[Show hide fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android)
using this code

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
          .show(somefrag)
          .commit();
```

... but my question here is how to extend one of the left fragments to expand and fill its place so i don't have an empty area and instead fill the screen..???

Here is my Activity layout having the 3 containers

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip" />

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFF42" />

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/container3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip" />
```

Comment: can you post your layout ??

Comment: ive updated the question with the layout @Pankaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the visibility of its container:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.container3);
container.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: ewww... yeah that helped.... i was trying to hide the fragment and forgot about hiding the container reserving space for it..thanks pal @ilovemyponcho