# hide existing fragment and load new one on same frame

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use the one frame on which changing the fragment views, the problem I have is when I place add instead of replace the new view is placed on the existing one

all I need is it has to replace the existing and place the new one

As I have to reuse the current view when back button is pressed cannot use the replace

```
Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new DetailFragment2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.frame_container2, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Possible duplication of the below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the support library (which is your actual case), use this code:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft =
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container2, new DetailFragment2());
ft.commit();
```

If one day you'll decide to use the support library, then use this instead (it's only a matter of replacing `getFragmentManager()` with `getSupportFragmentManager()`):

```
final FragmentTransaction ft =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_container2, new DetailFragment2());
ft.commit();
```

Comment: all i need is replace functionality with add it may sounds odd but my req is i has a list view which is downloaded from rest call and when i click on a item it is calling the detail activity and when i press back it has to return to the old view

Comment: My answer is a solution for `hide existing fragment and load new one on same frame` and `all I need is it has to replace the existing and place the new one`. So, in `onCreate()` load the first Fragment. when you click some Button or whatever, replace it with se second one. in `onBackPressed()`, reload the Activity (which, in turn, will reload the first Fragment) - or simply replace the second Fragment with the first one.

Comment: @KlingKlang And how exactly can we "simply replace the second Fragment with the first one" if it's been removed and recreation launches a network request which might return different results this time?

Comment: @kaay You should have a method which allows you to get the same results based on the same conditions (a query or whatever).

Comment: @KlingKlang That sounds like really, really bad advice. The request gets the most recent posts, or somesuch, and the service might not be mine to modify to add a functionality like this - not to mention... can you imagine trying to JUSTIFY such a change?
I've tried the instancestate bundle, but, after an hour of boilerplating, bound out the mechanism isn't even used in Fragment replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction;
            transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
           transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container2,fragment.newIstance());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

And you need to create newIstance in Fragment class:

```
public static fragment newIstance(){
        fragment frag= new fragment();
        return frag;
    }
```