# Add several back stack entries within single fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I need to display a `Fragment` with 2 fragments before it being added into back stack. However `addToBackStack` method belongs to `FragmentTransaction` so I cannot add all three of them in the single `FragmentTransaction` cause all three of them will be removed by back button click. But if I use three different `FragmentTransation`s then until the third fragment becomes visible two previous ones become visible to the user too.

Is there a way I can add three `Fragment`s into back stack without making first two of them visible during transaction?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that using the native API. Nonetheless you can implement your own stack using the [Queue Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately I need to use the native API because I need my code to be compatible with older version.

Comment: No links between using Queue Interface (Java Context) and old android versions (Android Context). I mean this is not because you implement your own stack (using Queue Interface) that your code will not be compatible with the oldest android versions

Comment: My code is an Android library. It'll be incompatible with some of my library users' integrations if I switch to custom queue.

Answer (score 0):

add an OnBackStackChangedListener to fragmentmanager , then when the last backstack entry is fragment 2 popBackStack two times like this :

```
 0 FragmentHome ( back_stack_name : "fragment_home" ) 
 1 Fragment1( back_stack_name : "fragment_1" ) 
 2 Fragment2 ( back_stack_name : "fragment_2" ) 
 3 Fragment3 ( back_stack_name : "fragment_3" )
```

## code :

note that you should add OnBackStackChangedListener in fragment3 and then after poping backstack remove it from fragmentmanager

```
    // add in fragment3
        final FragmentManager fragment_manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragment_manager
                    .addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onBackStackChanged() {
                            if (fragment_manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                                String last_fragment_name = getLastBackStackFragmentName(fragment_manager);
                                if (last_fragment_name.equals("fragment_2")) {
                                      fragment_manager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
                                     fragment_manager.popBackStack();
                                     fragment_manager.popBackStack();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });

        private String getLastBackStackFragmentName(FragmentManager fragment_manager ) {
            int back_stack_count =fragment_manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            String last_fragment_name = "";
            if (back_stack_count>0) {
                last_fragment_name = fragment_manager.getBackStackEntryAt(
                        back_stack_count).getName();
            }
            return last_fragment_name;
        }
```

Comment: If I understand you right then after clicking back button on Fragment3 I'll be navigated to HomeFragment. I need an opposite: after clicking back button on Fragment3 I should be navigated to Fragment2 but when I'm adding the Fragment3 into fragment manager I should also add Fragment1 and Fragment2 but in a way user can't notice it.

Comment: @Lingviston hide those two fragments after they are added to backstack and then show them after fragment 3 is shown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android

Comment: funny thing is that I already ended up doing it this way:D But thanks anyway!