# Using livedata in fragments causing loss of state with bottomNavigation and NavigationController

Tags: android, uinavigationcontroller, android-livedata, bottomnavigationview, android-viewmodel

I have been trying to find the cause and the solution for the loss of states and recreating the fragments of bottom navigation when I use LiveData and MutableLiveData data inside a fragment in NavigationController. and also the ViewModel also loses the data if initialized inside the fragment.

Tried every possible way but had no luck.

Currently, I am storing the data in a ViewModel inside activity to keep the data.

Hope anyone else has a solution

Thanks

Comment: how are you initialising the view model?

Comment: chatViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[ChatViewModel::class.java]

Comment: in side oncreate function in my fragment

Comment: you can use this method -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347588/show-hide-fragment-in-android

Comment: @KamalNayan my issue is with Navigation Controller, ViewModel and LiveData.